ubuntu xbox series x controller - detected but mappings don't register
Ubuntu is able to recognize my controller and using jstest-gtk and antimicrox shows that my button presses are being captured. However, when I try to map buttons to keyboard and mouse inputs, none of it works. Going back to antimicrox interface still shows my controller inputs being captured though.
When I open steam, I am able to navigate around the menus and such. How come my controller is recognized but buttons are not mapping?
I'm have both windows and linux installed (not sure if relevant). The controller mapping works perfectly fine in windows using joy2key
edit: i disabled all the controller settings in steam, and somehow the antimicrox mappings work in steam only. please advise
edit2: today, i boot up the computer, and the controller works. All I ran was sudo modprobe xpad to detect it. I've restarted numerous times to linux and windows before, so I have no idea why it works today. but problem solved.

today, i boot up the linux in recovery mode, and the controller works. All I ran was sudo modprobe xpad to detect it. I've restarted numerous times to linux and windows before. It seems to only work in recovery mode.
